# VGG-19 value error - Negative dimension size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, faster-rcnn

I'm going to develop a cnn model similer to VGG-19. Model code is as follows.

```
model = Sequential([
    #layer set 1 VGG-19
    Input(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(64, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(64, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), data_format='channels_last'),

    #layer set 2
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(128, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(128, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), data_format='channels_last'),

    #layer set 3
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(256, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(256, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(256, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(256, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), data_format='channels_last', padding='same'),

    #layer set 4
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(512, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(512, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(512, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1), data_format='channels_last'),
    Conv2D(512, 3, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'),
    MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), data_format='channels_last'),

    #layer set output
    Flatten(),
    Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(1000, activation='softmax')
])
```

When I bulding tha model it gives following error.

```
Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_10/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,1,512].
```

keras 2 don't have 'dim_ordering' attribute. So I added 'data_format'. How can I solve that problem?

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: What are the values of IMG_HEIGHT and IMG_WIDTH?

Comment: I'm afraid the code you posted doesn't correspond to the error message... Your paddings in the code guarantee that this problem doesn't happen. Unless you're using image sizes <= 0, which should bring another error right at the beginning?

Comment: IMG_HEIGHT and IMG_WIDTH is 224

Comment: @DanielMöller the error message gives when I'm compiling the model. I included screeenshot above.

Comment: See in the stack trace (it's above the lines shown in the picture) which layer is problematic, build the model only up to the good layer before it and print the summary to see the shapes.